# SSRS static header repeating in other page

Tags: reporting-services, header, repeat

I already configured in the screenshot to repeat the header however I am getting this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error says it all.. you can't just have one member as True for repeating and the others as False.. either all repeat or none!

Comment: Thanks Harry it work..